# How do publish mediaStream to mediaServer from WEB without flash

Tags: javascript, audio, video

I want publise liveStream what collected by web to mediaServer without flash, flash is desperated。

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you want and what you have tried?

Comment: Hi brother，i want to push live-stream(video and audio)  to media-server without flash

Comment: in browser,and using javascript.

Comment: Not enough information to help you... **(1)** Do you have a live stream? **(2)** Do you have a media server? **(3)** Which part of your question are stuck with? Do you have a Flash version now that we see and advise how to do it _"without flash"_?